# Is there any difference between using IIFY(Immediately-Invoked Function Expression) and {...}

Tags: javascript, module

```js
(function() {
  let val = 10;
  console.log(val); // 10
})() // executed immediately
console.log(val); // val is not defined
```

VS

```js
{
    let val = 10;
    console.log(val); //10 
} // executed immediately
console.log(val) // val is not defined
```

Both code snippets seem to have the same effect. Can these two approaches be used interchangeably? Am i missing something?

Comment: Block works only if you use `const` or `let`. `var` would scope itself to the nearest function (or global, if none exists).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a block and `let` will have the same effect, but be more efficient than the IIFE in this case.

The IIFE pattern predates `let` being added to the JavaScript language so it is more common (and supported in IE10 and earlier).